# brew doctor giving error on a directory that has been removed

Tags: macos, bash, path, homebrew, .bash-profile

I just installed homebrew and as suggested, I ran the `brew doctor` command. I am linux newbie and do not know how to fix most of these things. But I would like to ask especially about the following error since I thought it would be fixed by what I did. The first time I ran `brew doctor` I got the following as one of many errors:

```
Error: Some directories in your path end in a slash.
Directories in your path should not end in a slash. This can break other
doctor checks. The following directories should be edited:
    /Applications/Mkvtoolnix.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

I deleted the Mkvtoolnix.app from my Mac using `rm -r Mkvtoolnix.app`. I do not see it anymore when I do `ls` in `/Applications`. However, when I run `brew doctor`, I still see the same error. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your PATH variable.

You need to start by finding where your PATH is currently being set, it is most likely `~/.bash_profile`, but it could be set elsewhere.

Your PATH is the list of directories that Bash (and other shells) looks in when looking for commands.  It is what saves you from having to type `/usr/bin/local/programname` every time you want to run `programname`.  You merely add `/usr/bin/local` to your path and bash indexes everything in that folder.